# How do I get the url to an api knowing the request url and headers

Tags: python, json, api, url, formatting

I wanted to view the raw api data by just typing the url into my browser but I'm not sure how to format the url. Is there a way I can use my python request to get the url I need with the headers included in it?

For example when i type in the request.url : https://free-geo-ip.p.rapidapi.com/json/[my_ip]

I get the error: `{"message":"Missing RapidAPI application key. Go to https:\/\/docs.rapidapi.com\/docs\/keys to learn how to get your API application key."}`

I have my api key and host which are the headers, I just don't know how to put them in the url.

Here's my python code with my ip address and api key taken out:

```py
import requests

url = "https://free-geo-ip.p.rapidapi.com/json/(my ip address)"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "free-geo-ip.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "(my api key)"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

r = response.json
```

Comment: Show the python code you use

Comment: In Google Chrome, you can use this extension to modify headers: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

Comment: I wanted to know how you can put the headers into the url to get the api data

Comment: Basic usage looks right, check rapidapi docs if you're using the right headers for key and url. Also it should be response.json() with parenthesis, and if you are using keyargs you should probably try use method= and url= as well

Comment: I can access it fine through python, I just want to know how i can view the api data in my browser. Like how do i fit my headers into the url if I wanted to access the api outside of python?

Comment: You can't add them to the URL, headers are separate to the URL. Check out the extension in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, you can use this extension to modify headers: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using postman to call apis without code.